# Which header are GCC macros stored ? I needed to create some tags from those files

Tags: gcc, macros, header

I'm wondering where are gcc macros like **builtin_expect , __attribute** ((warn_unused_result)) etc. stored ? I needed to create a tag file with ctags , for things like those above.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[_builtin_expect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) is a GCC builtin, this means that the compiler has some special code to handle it. It it nowhere really defined; if you care about its implementation, look inside the file [`gcc/builtins.c`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/gcc/builtins.c) (& `builtins.def`) of the GCC 4.6 (or future 4.7) compiler source code.

Likewise, `__attribute__`-s are handled by the compiler.

The GCC documentation lists the set of builtins & attributes understood by GCC. Plugins (or [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extensions) for GCC can augment it.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these, like all `__attribute__()` are special keywords handled directly by the compiler.